# Secure my applcation used file in sdcard android

Tags: android, security, encryption, android-sdcard

I have use AES encryption to secure my data in sdcard.It work fine but take some time to decrypt mp3 file as file size is large.

when I checked file stored in other application like whats-app ,Facebook etc.. it is encrypted in different way.

Is there is any other option which I can apply to secure my files in sdcard. Please help me.

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html) could help.

Comment: I gone through this but don't know how to implement in my case,can you please provide a demo project.

Answer (score 0):

First, I will start my mentioning that you should evaluate files size and encryption/decryption time versus file importance. For example, we may want a 500mb file be only accessible by our application through Android, in which case we can set the required permissions. Because this file is not that important for us, we may decide not to encrypt it and encrypt the small and important files.

This said, I would suggest looking into faster/less reliable encryption schemes which will produce faster results. Following that you mentioned Facebook, you can look at [Conceal](https://facebook.github.io/conceal/), an open source framework developed by Facebook.

Comment: I have many .mp3 file in sdcard.I tried to encrypt my 7MB .mp3 file using AES but it take few seconds to decrypt so it make a user a delay.In my application music have to change immediately when user touch on screen. Insead on AES can I use DES to encrypt my mp3 file to fast it.

Comment: Repeating myself here...first, are these mp3 files worth the encryption? Using encryption for a "music player" style application sounds quite inconvenient. Second, yeah using DES may result in faster decryption, as well as using shorter key for AES (128/256/512/1024). Most importantly, do you need to decrypt/encrypt every mp3 file on request? Why don't, just decrypt all the required files on application start?